# How to add space between math symbols faster than existing methods

Tags: spacing, horizontal

I have several equations that needs extra space between math symbols. Is there any way to add space between each symbol faster than adding

```
\,
\:
\quad
```

etc, to the code?

It takes a lot of time to add the extra space for each equation in each space between symbols

I am using this code to add extra space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{ModeloFactorizandolasK}
\dot{N_1} ={p}_{11}\,r_{1}' \,N_1 ( K_1-p_{11}N_1+p_{21}N_2 )\, + \,p_{12}\,r_2' \,N_1
( K_2\,-\,p_{12}\,N_1\,+\,p_{22}\,N_2 )
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a manual or an automatic solution? Because as far as manual solutions go the two keystrokes of `\,` `\;` `\:` can hardly be beaten (I admit `\quad` is longer ...). If you want an automatic solution you would have to explain a rule that says where to add what kind of space.

Comment: personally I would definitely write `\left( K_2\,-\,p_{12}\,N_1\,+\p_{22}\,N_2 \right)` as `( K_2-p_{12}N_1+\p_{22}N_2)` so no `\,` and no `\left\right`

Comment: also if you are looking for typing speedups `^\prime` can be written as `'`

Comment: @moewe The rule is that always add space between any symbol

Comment: @moewe Yes, I am looking for an automatic solution, I suppose I am searching for something like a math environment that gives more space between the symbols. This environment would help me to save time, avoiding me write each extra space.

Comment: All of your `\,` tokens are wrong. They lower the readability of the formula, rather than enhancing it. There is no reason for `p_{11}\,r_{1}'\,N_1` at the beginning and `p_{11}N_1` inside the parentheses. By the way, `^'` is wrong and should be just `'`. Also, `\dot{N_1}` should be `\dot{N}_1` for best placement of the dot.

Answer (score 3):

I think (2) with the default TeX spacing looks best but (3) has automatically added space similar to the space added by the explicit `\,` in setting (1)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{eepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}


aaa
\begin{equation}
\dot{N_1} ={p}_{11}\,r_{1}' \,N_1 ( K_1-p_{11}N_1+p_{21}N_2 )\, + \,p_{12}\,r_2' \,N_1
( K_2\,-\,p_{12}\,N_1\,+\,p_{22}\,N_2 )
\end{equation}


bbb
\begin{equation}
\dot{N_1} ={p}_{11}r_{1}' N_1 ( K_1-p_{11}N_1+p_{21}N_2 ) + p_{12}r_2' N_1
( K_2-p_{12}N_1+p_{22}N_2 )
\end{equation}


\thinmuskip=4mu
\medmuskip=6mu plus 4mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=7mu plus 7mu
\scriptspace=1pt
ccc
\begin{equation}
\dot{N_1} ={p}_{11}r_{1}' N_1 ( K_1-p_{11}N_1+p_{21}N_2 ) + p_{12}r_2' N_1
( K_2-p_{12}N_1+p_{22}N_2 )
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do yo use in the code  \thinmuskip=4mu
\medmuskip=6mu plus 4mu minus 4mu
\thickmuskip=7mu plus 7mu
\scriptspace=1pt ?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz tex adds thin medium or thick space in several places, eg `=` is a relation so gets thick space on either side, I increased the value of the thick space from its default value of 5mu to 7mu, so you get more space in the equation, as asked. medmuskip similarly changes the space around binary operators like `+`.

Comment: the code you presented modify the spaces over the whole document?, if I am right that would be unconvenient for me because I just need it for the specific equation.

Comment: @JuanMuñoz your question explicitly talked of spacing all equations `It takes a lot of time to add the extra space for each equation in each space between symbols`  However it is Ok: you can do either, they are local settings so if you just want to affect one place them in any `{...}` group or an environment or anything else that keeps settings local.

Comment: So I should add to the commands \thinmuskip the braquets {...}, to make de modification local?

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any space between e.g. two Greek symbols...

Comment: @StephaneBersier no it adds space after subscripts and superscripts and around binary relations and operators. not bwen symbols (whether latin or greek alphabet)  But it's best not to add the spaces at all.